# JSON Array to data model

Tags: android, kotlin

I have reply JSON that must populate the response model I've created below. The last JSON node OPTIONLIST is a JSON array without a @SerializedName. How do I add this JSON array in my model if the JSON Array doesn't have a @SerializedName?

I have added the JSON documentation provided by the backend server person.

```
class OrderFutureResponseModel {

    data class OrderFutureList(
        @SerializedName("DBTNO")
        val DbtNo: String = "",
        @SerializedName("FANME")
        val FName: String = "",
        @SerializedName("SNAME")
        val SName: String = "",
        @SerializedName("EMPNO")
        val EmpNo: String = "",
        @SerializedName("TEL")
        val tel: String = "",
        @SerializedName("EMAIL")
        val email: String = "",
        @SerializedName("CURBAL")
        val curBal: String = "",
        @SerializedName("EXCLUDEDBAL")
        val exclBal: String = "",
        @SerializedName("RECEIPTHTML")
        val recHTML: String = "",
        @SerializedName("OPTIONS")
        val options: List<orderFutureOptions> = ArrayList(),
        @SerializedName("OPTIONLIST")
        val optionList: List<orderFutureOptionList> = ArrayList()
    )

    data class orderFutureOptions(
        @SerializedName("DAY")
        val optionsDay: String = "",
        @SerializedName("DATE")
        val optionsDate: String = "",
        @SerializedName("SECSTART")
        val secStart: String = "",
        @SerializedName("SECEND")
        val secEnd: String = "",
        @SerializedName("PREPMIN")
        val preMin: String = ""
    )

    data class orderFutureOptionList(
        //@SerializedName("")
        val optionListDtl: String = ""
    )
}


//JSON Documentation provided
Reply Json Data :
{
“DBTNO”:”char(9)”,
“FANME”:”char(30)”,
“SNAME”:”char(50)”,
“EMPNO”:”char(20)”,
“TEL”:”char(14)”,
“EMAIL”:”char(50)”,
“CURBAL”:num,   (balance field to be used)
“EXCLUDEDBAL”:num  (For future use)
“RECEIPTHTML”: Last printed receipt from dbtdet in HTML format
If the site is configured with future orders the following arrays will be added at the end of the json
“OPTIONS”: [
{“DAY”: Char, (Today,Tomorrow,Monday,…, Sunday)
“DATE”: "2019-09-02T00:00:00",
“SECSTART”: num, (Seconds since midnight) Trading start time
“SECEND”: num, (Seconds since midnight) Trading end time
“PREPMIN”: num (Minutes required to prep)  && Only applicable for today’s order
},…
],
“OPTIONLIST”:[{“Collect”,”Deliver”,…..}]  (If list empty do not show the option)
}

//JSON RESULT
{
  "DBTNO": "5HV0GMIXB",
  "FNAME": "Levi",
  "SNAME": "Sebastian Bands",
  "EMPNO": "9002",
  "TEL": "+27825671090",
  "EMAIL": "bart.rouan@intelipos.com",
  "CURBAL": 4143.11,
  "EXCLUDEDBAL": 500.00,
  "RECEIPTHTML": "",
  "OPTIONS": [
    {
      "DAY": "Today",
      "DATE": "2021-03-29T00:00:00",
      "SECSTART": 27000,
      "SECEND": 61200,
      "PREPMIN": 30
    },
    {
      "DAY": "Tomorrow",
      "DATE": "2021-03-30T00:00:00",
      "SECSTART": 27000,
      "SECEND": 61200,
      "PREPMIN": 0
    },
    {
      "DAY": "Wednesday",
      "DATE": "2021-03-31T00:00:00",
      "SECSTART": 27000,
      "SECEND": 61200,
      "PREPMIN": 0
    },
    {
      "DAY": "Thursday",
      "DATE": "2021-04-01T00:00:00",
      "SECSTART": 27000,
      "SECEND": 61200,
      "PREPMIN": 0
    },
    {
      "DAY": "Saturday",
      "DATE": "2021-04-03T00:00:00",
      "SECSTART": 27000,
      "SECEND": 50400,
      "PREPMIN": 0
    },
    {
      "DAY": "Tuesday",
      "DATE": "2021-04-06T00:00:00",
      "SECSTART": 27000,
      "SECEND": 61200,
      "PREPMIN": 0
    },
    {
      "DAY": "Wednesday",
      "DATE": "2021-04-07T00:00:00",
      "SECSTART": 27000,
      "SECEND": 61200,
      "PREPMIN": 0
    }
  ],
  "OPTIONLIST": [
    "Collect",
    "Collect from Reception",
    "Deliver to Boardroom"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you post the original response

Comment: @ELTEGANIMOHAMEDHAMADGABIR I've added the JSON documentation provided

Comment: invalid JSON check this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: It was documentation not the JSON. I have added the JSON result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, what you're saying is that one of the JSON Array doesn't contain a key so how to parse it.

Just change `val optionList: List<orderFutureOptionList> = ArrayList()` as `val optionList: List<String> = ArrayList()`. Because what you're getting is an array of Strings.

Comment: So simple and got stuck on this, thank you.